# Passing data to Google Charts with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

This question has been asked but not answered like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723648/django-with-google-charts).

In my `view.py` I have data pulled from MySQL, example of the array:

```
(Decimal('13'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('13'))
(Decimal('207'), Decimal('18'), Decimal('129'))
(Decimal('301'), Decimal('38'), Decimal('193'))
(Decimal('204'), Decimal('32'), Decimal('150'))
(Decimal('159'), Decimal('25'), Decimal('88'))

args = {'array':array}
return render_to_response('page2.html', args)
```

Trying to put it into Google Chart

```
function drawChart() {
    var djangoData = JSON.parse('{{ args }}');
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoData);
```

Also tried `var djangoData = {{ array }};`
Both with no luck!

**Edit**:

Suggested

```
return render_to_response('page2.html', {'array': json.dumps(array)})
```

Looks like it would work, except that the db produces incompatible type. Is there a way to do this without converting every item to `int` type. Or if there if there is a pythonic way to convert it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try this in *view.py* (do not forget to add the `import json`):

```
array = [['X', 'Y', 'Z'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
return render_to_response('page2.html', {'array': json.dumps(array)})
```

Then in the template use the raw value **array** without quotes:

```
var djangoData = {{ array|safe }};
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoData);
```

**EDIT:** using a custom JSONEncoder to handle the `Decimal` type, stolen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object):

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return float(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)
```

Then in the view:

```
array = [['X', 'Y', 'Z'], [Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3')]]
return render_to_response('page2.html', {
    'array': json.dumps(array, cls=DecimalEncoder),
})
```

Comment: Get Decimal('13') is not JSON serializable, which seems to be a problem due to the DB output. Is there a way to deal with that without remaking the output into different type? Not familiar with this aspect at all. Thanks tho, this seems like the right track for sure

Comment: You will need to convert your array (e.g. `Decimal` to `int`), or use a custom JSON serializer to handle the conversion on the fly (it's really not that complicated). Please update your question with an example of your array.

Comment: Now there is some witchcraft going on. So `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['X', 'Y', 'Z'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` works fine but when i do `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{array}}) with data like
`[["X", "Y", "Z"], [13.0, 6.0, 13.0], [207.0, 18.0, 129.0]]` I get nothing. That is a snippet from print in `html`. Data seems to be all correct and I pass column names... but nothing

Comment: Fixed it! Needed to change `{{array}}` to `{{array|safe}}`

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to use arrayToDataTable to create a positive/negative column bar chart? I have successfully passed data from view to draw the chart, but can't seem to draw a normal column chart, but struggling to produce a positive/negative column chart. Someone take this to chat.